# What is the difference between String.Intern and String.IsInterned?

Tags: c#, .net, string

MSDN states that

> String.Intern retrieves the system's
>   reference to the specified  String

and

> String.IsInterned retrieves a
>   reference to a specified  String.

I think that IsInterned should have returned (I know it doesn't) a bool stating whether the specified string is interned or not. Is that correct thinking ? I mean it is atleast not consistent with .net framework naming convention.

I wrote the following code:

```
    string s = "PK";
    string k = "PK";

    Console.WriteLine("s has hashcode " + s.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("k has hashcode " + k.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("PK Interned " + string.Intern("PK"));
    Console.WriteLine("PK IsInterned " + string.IsInterned("PK"));
```

The output is :

**s has hashcode -837830672**

**k has hashcode -837830672**

**PK Interned PK**

**PK IsInterned PK**

Why is string.IsInterned("PK") returning "PK"?

Comment: If you want to know more about the details of strings and interning please see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372547/where-do-java-and-net-string-literals-reside/372559#372559

Comment: The name is very booleanish. Perhaps it was a typo of "IfInterned".

Comment: Remark to your use of `GetHashCode`: Please note that the `System.String` class *overrides* `GetHashCode()`. So such a method call is not useful to check if the instances might be different. Instead include a `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` directive and use `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(string)`. Here is a good example: `string s = "PK"; string t = 'P'.ToString() + "K"; Console.WriteLine("s has non-overridden hashcode " + RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(s)); Console.WriteLine("t has non-overridden hashcode " + RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(t));`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`String.Intern` interns the string if it's not already interned; `String.IsInterned` doesn't.

`IsInterned("PK")` is returning "PK" because it's already interned. The reason for it returning the string instead of a `bool` is so that you can easily get a reference to the interned string itself (which may not be the same reference as you passed in). In other words, it's effectively returning two related pieces of information at once - you can simulate it returning `bool` easily:

```
public static bool IsInternedBool(string text)
{
     return string.IsInterned(text) != null;
}
```

I agree that the naming isn't ideal, although I'm not sure what would have been better: `GetInterned` perhaps?

Here's an example showing that difference though - I'm not using string literals, to avoid them being interned beforehand:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string first = new string(new[] {'x'});
        string second = new string(new[] {'y'});

        string.Intern(first); // Interns it
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(first) != null); // Check

        string.IsInterned(second); // Doesn't intern it
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(second) != null); // Check
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the answer. Is it correct to think that declaration of string s must have interned "PK". Then what will String.Intern("PK") do?

Comment: All literal strings are interned by default.

Comment: @PK, if the string has already been interned, then Intern will return the exact same reference that was passed in.  I wasn't aware of the fact that literals are interned automatically, but it completely makes sense.

Comment: Then, how to construct a string that is *not* interned?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: `new String(String)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, don't get you. `new String(String)` will not compile.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Whoops, hadn't checked the tags. Was looking for a `String(String)` constructor, which exists in Java. You can use `new string(text.ToCharArray())` which will always create a new string object *unless* `text` is an empty string, in which case - at least in some versions of .NET - you'll still get a reference back which refers to an existing object.

Comment: @JonSkeet but this makes even less sense! because for any given empty string, `ReferenceEquals("", string.Empty)` always returns `true`, right? I would assume the empty string to be definitely interned always.