# Question about figures in C# dump heap analysis

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-management, dump, dotmemory

I'm using `!dumpheap -stat` for investigating a C# application dump, I have taken the dump using "C:\Windows\Syswow64\TaskMgr.exe". I have a question concerning the numbers I see:

```
!dumpheap -stat
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.7.3946.0
SOS Version: 4.8.9195.0
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
0b79f9b8        1           12 System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[[Location, ProductShared]]
0b797500        1           12 Product.TelegramManager+<>c
0b796d78        1           12 Product.UdpConnection+<>c__DisplayClass11_1
     ...      ...          ... ...
08205080     8601       791292 System.Net.Sockets.Socket
05fe3c04    24246      1066824 System.Threading.ExecutionContext
050afd98    19003      1119064 System.String
050e6fdc    10489      1771710 System.Byte[]
06135068     7812      2031120 System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs
00f0bcd0    19572    892214388      Free
```

The total size of the file (in bytes):

```
"C:\Temp_Folder\ProductServer (2).DMP" 1.113.058.732
```

This is in line with what I see in Windows explorer (1.086.972 KB).

The total amount of "TotalSize" (except "Free") equals 14841410.
Adding the "Totalsize" of "Free" equals 907.055.798.

None of those values corresponds with the total size of the dumpfile, so I'm wondering:

- Can I even use `!dumpheap -stat` for investigating the memory usage of my C# application?
- Is there a difference between managed memory usage and native memory usage (which might explain the enormous value for "Free" in the `!dumpheap -stat` result)?
- What is the exact relation between `!dumpheap -stat` result and file size of the dump?

**Edit after first dotMemory analysis of the dump:**

My suspicions seem to be confirmed by a first glance at a JetBrains "dotMemory" analysis:

[image]

As you can see, only a small ±13Mb is occupied by objects, so why is the total size of the dump larger than 1Gb?

**Edit: Memory snapshot, as shown in dotMemory**

In dotMemory, the memory snapshot looks as follows:

[image]

In my humble opinion, this means that ±865Mb is present in the dump without even being used.

How is this possible?

**Edit: investigation of pinned objects:**
In [the referred post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562500/how-to-determine-why-an-object-is-pinned), there are two commands: `!gcroot <memory_address>` and `!eehead -gc`, hereby the results of those commands:

`!gcroot <memory_address` of one of the `System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs` objects:

```
0:000> !gcroot 02d259f8
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.7.3946.0
SOS Version: 4.8.9195.0
HandleTable:
    00e726fc (async pinned handle)
    -> 030b6f84 System.Threading.OverlappedData
    -> 02d2a01c System.Threading.IOCompletionCallback
    -> 02d259f8 System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs

Found 1 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
```

(The result "async **pinned** handle" gives me the impression I'm dealing with a pinned object indeed.)

Hereby the results of the `eeheap -gc` command:

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.7.3946.0
SOS Version: 4.8.9195.0
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x60131f04
generation 1 starts at 0x600c1000
generation 2 starts at 0x02b71000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
02b70000  02b71000  03824fec  0xcb3fec(13320172)
15700000  15701000  162ec0bc  0xbeb0bc(12497084)
11700000  11701000  1229a258  0xb99258(12161624)
14700000  14701000  15356178  0xc55178(12931448)
16700000  16701000  171d2ec4  0xad1ec4(11345604)
19700000  19701000  1a2250fc  0xb240fc(11682044)
1a700000  1a701000  1b2ebbc0  0xbeabc0(12495808)
17700000  17701000  18215dc0  0xb14dc0(11619776)
10020000  10021000  10af8f94  0xad7f94(11370388)
13700000  13701000  1436bea8  0xc6aea8(13020840)
18700000  18701000  191b3024  0xab2024(11214884)
1d4c0000  1d4c1000  1df235a0  0xa625a0(10888608)
0dea0000  0dea1000  0e9b5a5c  0xb14a5c(11618908)
1f540000  1f541000  1ffcd6d4  0xa8c6d4(11060948)
1e4c0000  1e4c1000  1f0044e0  0xb434e0(11810016)
12700000  12701000  131b0d50  0xaafd50(11205968)
20540000  20541000  21071efc  0xb30efc(11734780)
22540000  22541000  2304c388  0xb0b388(11580296)
23540000  23541000  23ff2aec  0xab1aec(11213548)
24540000  24541000  24ff1fc0  0xab0fc0(11210688)
21540000  21541000  21fc6150  0xa85150(11030864)
27540000  27541000  28089918  0xb48918(11831576)
26540000  26541000  27076b44  0xb35b44(11754308)
25540000  25541000  2601f3a4  0xade3a4(11396004)
1c4c0000  1c4c1000  1cf12e3c  0xa51e3c(10821180)
2a540000  2a541000  2b0a243c  0xb6143c(11932732)
28540000  28541000  2906b6d4  0xb2a6d4(11708116)
2c540000  2c541000  2cfa5538  0xa64538(10896696)
2b540000  2b541000  2bf1ea28  0x9dda28(10345000)
29540000  29541000  29f7649c  0xa3549c(10704028)
2f540000  2f541000  2fee349c  0x9a249c(10101916)
2d540000  2d541000  2df41b38  0xa00b38(10488632)
30540000  30541000  30f5da50  0xa1ca50(10603088)
2e540000  2e541000  2ef127a8  0x9d17a8(10295208)
360c0000  360c1000  36c1727c  0xb5627c(11887228)
370c0000  370c1000  37bfb8f8  0xb3a8f8(11774200)
32540000  32541000  33158778  0xc17778(12679032)
390c0000  390c1000  39c4fc54  0xb8ec54(12119124)
3b0c0000  3b0c1000  3bb78efc  0xab7efc(11239164)
3a0c0000  3a0c1000  3ac0482c  0xb4382c(11810860)
3c0c0000  3c0c1000  3cbb095c  0xaef95c(11467100)
380c0000  380c1000  38b3c34c  0xa7b34c(10990412)
3e0c0000  3e0c1000  3eb31580  0xa70580(10945920)
3f0c0000  3f0c1000  3fc9e148  0xbdd148(12439880)
3d0c0000  3d0c1000  3dcc34fc  0xc024fc(12592380)
400c0000  400c1000  40c4006c  0xb7f06c(12054636)
410c0000  410c1000  41b0297c  0xa4197c(10754428)
420c0000  420c1000  42b3fbbc  0xa7ebbc(11004860)
430c0000  430c1000  43c8c314  0xbcb314(12366612)
460c0000  460c1000  46f1e244  0xe5d244(15061572)
440c0000  440c1000  44c1bec8  0xb5aec8(11906760)
450c0000  450c1000  45b5d020  0xa9c020(11124768)
33540000  33541000  33f0129c  0x9c029c(10224284)
31540000  31541000  31f4505c  0xa0405c(10502236)
480c0000  480c1000  48bce7b4  0xb0d7b4(11589556)
4b0c0000  4b0c1000  4bb84104  0xac3104(11284740)
4a0c0000  4a0c1000  4ab2856c  0xa6756c(10909036)
470c0000  470c1000  47ab4618  0x9f3618(10434072)
490c0000  490c1000  49a9367c  0x9d267c(10299004)
4c0c0000  4c0c1000  4cabe870  0x9fd870(10475632)
4d0c0000  4d0c1000  4dbc46e0  0xb036e0(11548384)
4f0c0000  4f0c1000  4fbc6644  0xb05644(11556420)
4e0c0000  4e0c1000  4ebede38  0xb2ce38(11718200)
510c0000  510c1000  51b0b090  0xa4a090(10789008)
500c0000  500c1000  50a8b41c  0x9ca41c(10265628)
540c0000  540c1000  54bb6784  0xaf5784(11491204)
520c0000  520c1000  52afdf9c  0xa3cf9c(10735516)
530c0000  530c1000  53a924b4  0x9d14b4(10294452)
570c0000  570c1000  57b247d8  0xa637d8(10893272)
560c0000  560c1000  56ab2050  0x9f1050(10424400)
580c0000  580c1000  58b0bebc  0xa4aebc(10792636)
550c0000  550c1000  55a31710  0x970710(9897744)
590c0000  590c1000  59b4062c  0xa7f62c(11007532)
5b0c0000  5b0c1000  5ba4d478  0x98c478(10011768)
5c0c0000  5c0c1000  5cc10f3c  0xb4ff3c(11861820)
5a0c0000  5a0c1000  5aaa172c  0x9e072c(10356524)
5e0c0000  5e0c1000  5ecb2ff8  0xbf1ff8(12525560)
5d0c0000  5d0c1000  5d9a1d88  0x8e0d88(9309576)
5f0c0000  5f0c1000  5f9de694  0x91d694(9557652)
600c0000  600c1000  60b2bcc4  0xa6acc4(10923204)
Large object heap starts at 0x03b71000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
03b70000  03b71000  03cb8e48  0x147e48(1343048)
Total Size:              Size: 0x3611c380 (907133824) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:    Size: 0x3611c380 (907133824) bytes.
```

`gcroot` seems not to work very well (even without spelling mistakes :-) ):

```
0:000> !gcroot 0x03b71000
...
Found 0 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
0:000> !GCRoot -all
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.7.3946.0
SOS Version: 4.8.9195.0
Invalid argument -all
```

**Information for Eocron**:
Hereby the last lines of the `od -x ProductServer (2).DMP` WSL command (I tried using the HEX viewer of Notepad++ but this seems not to work well on such large files):

```
10225750420 0000 8000 0100 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000
10225750440 0000 0000 0000 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000
10225750460 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
10225750520 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
10225750540 0000 0000 504b fecd ffff ffff 0002 0000
10225750560 0001 0083 fe28 8dfb 1b3d 01da 5800 14c5
10225750600 3c3d 01da 0007 0000 0000 0000 0007 0000
10225750620 0000 0000 0340 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
10225750640 00a0 0000 00a0 0000 0100 0000 0240 0000
10225750660 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
10225750700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
10225751640 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0340 0000
10225751660 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
10225756640 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
10225756660 0000 0000 724e 65f4 b54b 0111 0000 0000
10225756700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
10225766640 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
10225766654
```

=> Eocron, can you confirm whether or not this looks like the assembly references you've mentioned?

**Information for dbc**:
I've done a `ping -n 100 <IP_Address>` for one of the IP addresses, used for setting up TCP sockets, hereby the result (summary):

```
Reply from <IP_Addr>: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=59 => 54 entries
Reply from <IP_Addr>: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=59 => 40 entries
Reply from <IP_Addr>: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=59 => 6  entries

Ping statistics for <IP_Addr>:
    Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 100, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms
```

... while, for another IP address, these are the results:

```
Reply from <IP_Addr2>: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=59 => 70 entries
Reply from <IP_Addr2>: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=59 => 25 entries
Reply from <IP_Addr2>: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=59 =>  4 entries
Reply from <IP_Addr2>: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=59 =>  1 entries

Ping statistics for <IP_Addr2>:
    Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 100, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 0ms
```

=> As you can see, there is some variation on the response time, but I don't know if this might be sufficient to explain the mentioned behaviour.

**Edit after comment from Alois Kraus:**
@[Alois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235660/alois-kraus), when a connection needs to be closed, I have the following piece of source code: (the connection is handled by a class, containing the property `_clientSocket` of the `Socket` class)
Can you confirm I should add the propose line?
Do you also know why the customer currently doesn't seem to have the memory leak? (The customer was before working on another Windows version, .Net framework 4.0, while now he is working on .Net framework 4.7)

```
Private Sub Socket_ConnectComplete(sender As Object, e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
If e.SocketError <> SocketError.Success Then
    // e.Dispose() <= should I add this line of source code?
    Disconnect()
    Return
End If

Public Sub Disconnect()
Try
    If _clientSocket IsNot Nothing Then
        _clientSocket.Close()
        _clientSocket = Nothing
    End If
...
End Sub
```

Comment: Taskmgr (MiniDumpWriteDump() really) doesn't know anything about managed code,  you get the whole kit and kaboodle.  What is labeled as free is *unused* space in GC heap segments.  Seeing too much of it isn't that unusual in a program that uses lots of async sockets, they have a knack for pinning the buffer while a read is in progress.  Such a pinned buffer prevents a heap segment from getting recycled.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562500/how-to-determine-why-an-object-is-pinned).

Comment: @HansPassant: pardon my ignorance but from your comment I learn that there is something, called a "pinned buffer" and that this behaviour seems to be normal. Unfortunately the fact that my application is taking more and more memory (±100Mb/day) is a real problem for my customer. Are you aware of any solution for this kind of behaviour? (I would prefer a solution without programming, like a .NET configuration modification for "unpinning" the buffers or clearing/flushing them.)

Comment: @HansPassant: I've updated my question again, adding the command results of the referred post. Unfortunately I don't know where to find the `!eehead` command. Do you know what I need to load for that?

Comment: @HansPassant: sometimes it's very clear that I'm stressed, when I start making spelling mistakes like that. Sorry for the inconvenience. Does the `eeheap -gc` command result give you any more information?

Comment: Maybe some background on this entire situation: my application has been copied from one computer to another. The only differences are the IP addresses, needed for connecting to the database. The initial application did not have a memory increase, the new one has (±100Mb per day). First I've seen traces of "Trend Micro" modules and threads inside my application (which are well known for exploding memory usage), but now I don't see Trend Micro modules nor threads in the new dump. (continue in next comment)

Comment: The fact that the memory keeps increasing (about 100Mb a day) is a real problem. It might be due to Trend Micro, being loaded and unloaded dynamically, or they might be another reason. As nothing has been changed in TCP socket handling (at least not in source code), the memory increase (if caused by TCP socket handling) should be part of the configuration of the computer. So basically, I'm wondering if there is any way to be sure **what** causes this memory increase: Trend Micro, TCP sockets, something else (what?), ...

Comment: ... I am capable of attaching the Visual Studio environment to the running application, but I have no experience in Visual Studio's diagnostics tools, hence my choice of taking a dump. I'll try to set up the diagnostics tools from Visual Studio and see if this works any better.

Comment: Are you allocating many objects larger than 85 KB that will end up on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951836)?  If so, you may be fragmenting your memory.  Try setting [`GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035550) and compacting from time to time and see if memory use stabilizes.

Comment: Also, [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs) is disposable, are you disposing of it properly? According to the [doc remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks) it is expected that you will construct a fixed number of them, reuse them, and then finally dispose of them or return them to some application pool later, are you following that pattern?

Comment: Try to open file in HEX editor and see at the end of it. Worth a try, last time I investigated such problem it was really unexpected. If you see many assembly references (!!which doesn't show up in windbg, they are easly spotted, cause they have readable string headers) - thats probably the reason and you not disposing something, like XmlSerializer with type which creates temporary assemblies for example. It could also be some COM objects or unmanaged resources you are leaking.

Comment: @dbc: I seem to be working with a too old version of .NET, because `GCSettings` does not even have a `LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` property. Asking the definition of `GCSettings`, I end up in the following decompiled DLL: `#region Assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0`.

Comment: @dbc: I have the impression from the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` that it's the idea to open a socket, use it and close it afterwards. My application leaves the socket open so that, at any time, messages can be send to my (server) application.

Comment: @dbc: as far as the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` are concerned, could this be caused by an unstable network? (If the network is unstable, socket related objects need to be recreated maybe without being properly disposed) In that case, what kind of tool can verify the stability of TCP network connections?

Comment: @dbc: I added some network related information.

Comment: @eocron: I added the last lines of the hexdump of the dump.

Comment: Nope, did you tried to manually just see them? They are ASCII encoded and seen in text view.

Comment: @eocron: I tried (in Notepad++, using normal text view), but all I see are some weirdly interpreted binary characters. Certainly no ASCII-encoded words or phrases.

Comment: @HansPassant: pardon my ignorance. I had never heard of pinned objects. This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490912) explains they are created, using the `fixed` keyword, but as the entire source code (general platform + auxiliary modules + customer specific modules) doesn't contain `fixed` as a keyword, I can confirm there are no pinned objects in my application.

Comment: If your application memory increases on a daily basis I would have 3 snapshots taken on a different consequent day and compare them to see what objects are surviving and what's new

Comment: How are you creating your sockets? As Hans did tell you you need to dispose SocketAsyncEventArgs. Are you doing this properly? Here is PR of NLog where this was done: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/315/files.

Comment: @AloisKraus: I've update my question again. Can you confirm the proposed line is correct? In case yes, you can add it as an answer, I'll check it and in case correct, I'll accept it and award you the bounty.

Comment: You need to dispose of it even in the error case. It needs to go when you see it for the last time, and you don't immediately pass it to the next async function.

Comment: @Dominique: You must dispose SocketAsyncEventArgs always, not just in the error case. If you do not have other code where the SocketAsyncEventArgs is used then you should be fine by disposing ist unconditionally. If you use it after it has been disposed you will get error back which you need to address then additionally.