# How to perform memory usage analysis of a C# application on a remote computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, debugging, memory-management

As mentioned in [Question about figures in C# dump heap analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571406), my C# application is taking more and more memory (±100Mb per day) on customer premises.

Taking a dump give me the information that only ±13Mb of the dump (with a total size of +1Gb) is used by .NET accessible objects, as mentioned in that same question.

Now I'm thinking of another approach: run diagnostics while the program is running, but problem: how to do that?

Visual Studio has diagnostic tools (like VSDiagnostics.exe), I have those on my local computer but not on customer system.
I might decide to copy `VSDiagnostics.exe` on the customer's computer, but then there's the story of the agent configs: this is the list I'm having on my PC:

```
Prompt>dir
...
16/10/2023  10:35               139 CpuUsageBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               202 CpuUsageHigh.json
16/10/2023  10:35               201 CpuUsageLow.json
16/10/2023  10:35               259 CpuUsageWithCallCounts.json
16/10/2023  10:35               147 DatabaseBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               150 DotNetAsyncBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               153 DotNetCountersBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               157 DotNetObjectAllocBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               224 DotNetObjectAllocLow.json
16/10/2023  10:35               148 EventsBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               145 FileIOBase.json
16/10/2023  10:35               222 PerfInstrumentation.json
          12 File(s)          2.147 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  239.720.914.944 bytes free
```

As you see, no agent configs for investigating memory usage (as this is normally not an issue with .NET applications, but I really do have that problem).

Apparently, memory usage can only be done on the computer where Visual Studio is installed (starting a diag session automatically starts the application on my local PC).

I can copy `VSDiagnostics.exe` on the customer's PC, but without the needed agent configs, this makes no sense.

Does anybody know how to perform memory usage profiling of a C# (.NET) application on a remote PC?

Comment: you can write a log file, that collects data about your program, but first you should check the code for lists that aren't cleared array that get increased and so on, as the code to allocated more and more memory, so it can be only zentral (global or by REF) Variables.

Comment: My program was behaving just fine before. It has been copied to another computer, the only difference is the IP address of the SQL-server database server, and the usage is the same as before. I'm expecting the problem to be caused by that new computer's configuration, not in the application itself, but an investigation of the application should give a lead on which configuration issue which needs to be addressed.

Comment: no the co9nfiguration can't be the problem, if the memory leakage is only on one computer, then the dotnet framework version should be check and patch level. Basically a dot net program independent of the programming language is converted into a IL code, which runs on the dotnet framework of the computer, so if both have all the same patches installed, they should behave the same. If that is not the case, it would be best to reinstall the computer with all patches. for me is unclear where the problem occurs.

Comment: If the new machine has tons and tons of memory then C# has no need to release it. Are you sure this is an actual issue?

Comment: @Charlieface: this is interesting: are you saying that the .NET garbage collector waits for the memory to be "full" before starting to clean it? That should be configurable, I would think. Do you know how to configure the garbage collector of a machine? Of how to do this per application?

Comment: I would recommend ensuring you have a testing environment that is representative of what your customers are using. If it works in test but not at the customer you need to figure out how the environments are different.

Comment: @Charlieface: I found this URL: I'll check it out this afternoon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector

Comment: See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461701/14868997 GC will run when it needs to. For generation 0 and 1 this is very often, but for long lived objects, and for the Large Object Heap, not very often at all.

Comment: ... but one thing I don't understand: as only ±13Mb of the total size of 1.086Mb is detected as used by .NET, then how could the garbage collector (which, in my opinion, only has access to .NET objects) remove those objects from memory? (See image screenshot of ".NET used" and ".NET total" in referred question)

Comment: Problems like this occur if the code generates a lot of temporary objects. Strings are immutable so string operations create new strings. The older strings are orphaned and need to be garbage-collected. If the code uses string splitting to process large CSV files the application can end up using 3-4x times as much RAM as the CSV if not more.

Comment: Similar problems can be caused by inserting items one by one in a list. Most containers use an array for storage. When that array is full, a new one is allocated with twice the size and the data gets copied there. The old one is orphaned. You can avoid this by using the `capacity` parameter in the container constructor

Comment: You can check whether the application allocates too much if you run it with the `Diagnostic` window open to memory usage. If you see a sawtooth image it means a lot of temporary objects get allocated and collected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for your elaborate comments, but from your explanation I understand that there's something wrong in the programming, causing that issue **always**. The situation I'm having is that the application is working fine on one PC but bad on another one, although exactly the same processing is done on both computers (I'm talking about a migration).