# Microsoft C# string documentation: Am I misinterpreting what I read, or is the documentation wrong?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2013

Being new to C#, I was reading some guide. About strings, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I read (highlighting is mine):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code,
>   the compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new
>   sequence of characters, and **the variable b continues to hold "h"**.
>
> ```
> string b = "h";
> b += "ello";
> ```

But trying the following code, it prints "hello".

```
string b = "h";
b += "ello";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b);
```

So, am I misinterpreting what I read, or is the documentation wrong? Any other option? :)

Comment: The documentation seems confusing to me as well. As far as I know b loses reference to "h" and gets a new reference to the new string "hello". Maybe they just expressed themselves a bit unclear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly the documentation is wrong and as you have already found a latter version has been corrected, although it too has some issues (See below).  But I think a better example would be

```
string b = "h";
string d = b;
d += "ello";
```

Now `b` is still "h" because the `+=` did not update the reference, but create a new `string` that `d` references.

Also it should be noted that there are 3 `strings` in this code.  First the `string` literal "h", then the `string` literal "ello" and finally the `string` "hello" that is created from the concatenation of the previous two.  Because all `string` literals are interned and interned strings are not garbage collected the only `string` of the 3 that will eventually be eligible for garbage collection is the "hello" that is currently referenced by `d`.  Although it is possible to turn `string` interning off in which case all three would eventually be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: you ought to add "and now the original object referenced by b is eligible for garbage collection." just to make it clearer what is happening

Comment: @StillLearnin Actually because of string interning it isn't.  See my update.

Comment: You're right! I learned something new today. If I could upvote your answer twice, I would.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see the problem is that I was looking at Visual Studio 2005 documentation, which was simply wrong. The right updated documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Note that the documentation had already been *amended* for [Visual Studio 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code,
>   the compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new
>   sequence of characters, and that new object is assigned to b. The
>   string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection.

But, as correctly pointed out by juharr in the comments below, **it was still wrong** in the sense that `"h"` is interned and never garbage collected.

Comment: Yeah that looks more like it is supposed to be

Comment: I don't think anything changed -- it's just badly worded in the old documentation.

Comment: @adv12 What I have highlighted in my question is certainly wrong. The rest I think I understand. I agree juharr answer gives a much better example.

Comment: @adv12 The old documentation was not fine. It was in fact wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry for adding to the confusion.

Comment: Though I have to wonder about the new documentation saying _The string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection._ Because string literals are interned and so it might actually not be garbage collected.

Comment: @juharr I think the documentation means `The old string reference by the b variable and containing "h" is now eligible for garbage collection`. It's an acceptable simplification of the concept, much better of the previous version at least :)

Comment: @Antonio It does a better job of explaining the concept of immutability and references, but since `string` is used as the example it's technically wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692303/intern-string-literals-misunderstanding.  And it doesn't even bother to mention what happens with the "ello" `string` that was also created.

Comment: @juharr Wow!! Yes, that's another pretty interesting thing to know. So, also in 2008 the documentation was wrong, just at least a little bit less dangerously wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the documentation is wrong: `d += "ello";` is a shortcut for `d = d + "ello";`

The string object itself is immutable but you assign a new string to an existing variable (d).