# Are strings garbage collected?

Tags: .net, string, exception, garbage-collection

I profiled my C# application for memory problems bc it threw the exception out of memory.

I found that I have >1gb of data of strings. Mostly made by htmlagilitypack. Are strings not collected? I seem to have a lot of string data. I'll make a note that i get the memory issue when i throw lots of regular exceptions when parsing pages.

Comment: Strings are garbage collected, if nothing else in your application references those strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings and Garbage Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423111/strings-and-garbage-collection)

Comment: each time the GC Collects() if a string is still in use or it has a root-ref then it will be promoted up the generations 0,1,2 and it isn't uncommon to see > 1gb string data. In what scope are you declaring and using the regular expressions as they are expensive? If the the OOM (second chance) exception is reliably reproducible,  you'll need to use `windbg` +`sos` to confirm strings is the actual root cause.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: exceptions, not regular expressions xD. The htmlagilitypack usage is declared inside the function and i dont keep references to anything. I just return an enum saying what kind of error i had or success. Which is why this is confusing. Nope, not reliable exceptions :(. Also it takes maybe 2 hours before the out of memory problem happens

Comment: @EricJ.: if you read that question its asking how to dispose on demand. Thats nothing like what i am asking

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid long-living strings to cause generation 2 garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957421/how-to-avoid-long-living-strings-to-cause-generation-2-garbage-collection)