# How to avoid long-living strings to cause generation 2 garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have an application where I keep log strings in circular buffers. When a log gets full, for every new insert, old strings will be released for garbage collection and then they are in generation 2 memory. Thus, eventually a generation 2 GC will happen, which I would like to avoid.

I tried to marshal the string into a struct. Surprisingly, I still get generation 2 GC:s. It seems the struct still keeps some reference to the string. Complete console app below. Any help appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct FixedString
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            private string str;

            public FixedString(string str)
            {
                this.str = str;
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct UTF8PackedString
        {
            private int length;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            private byte[] str;

            public UTF8PackedString(int length)
            {
                this.length = length;
                str = new byte[length];
            }

            public static implicit operator UTF8PackedString(string str)
            {
                var obj = new UTF8PackedString(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str));
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                Array.Copy(bytes, obj.str, obj.length);
                return obj;
            }
        }

        const int BufferSize = 1000000;
        const int LoopCount = 10000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
                "Type".PadRight(20), "Time", "GC(0)", "GC(1)", "GC(2)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                TestPerformance<string>(s => s);
                TestPerformance<FixedString>(s => new FixedString(s));
                TestPerformance<UTF8PackedString>(s => s);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void TestPerformance<T>(Func<string, T> func)
        {
            var buffer = new T[BufferSize];
            GC.Collect(2);
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            var initialCollectionCounts = new int[] { GC.CollectionCount(0), GC.CollectionCount(1), GC.CollectionCount(2) };
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < LoopCount; i++)
                buffer[i % BufferSize] = func(i.ToString());
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
                typeof(T).Name.PadRight(20),
                stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                (GC.CollectionCount(0) - initialCollectionCounts[0]),
                (GC.CollectionCount(1) - initialCollectionCounts[1]),
                (GC.CollectionCount(2) - initialCollectionCounts[2])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated code with UnsafeFixedString that does the required work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public unsafe struct UnsafeFixedString
        {
            private int length;

            private fixed char str[256];

            public UnsafeFixedString(int length)
            {
                this.length = length;
            }

            public static implicit operator UnsafeFixedString(string str)
            {
                var obj = new UnsafeFixedString(str.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                    obj.str[i] = str[i];                
                return obj;
            }
        }

        const int BufferSize = 1000000;
        const int LoopCount = 10000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
                "Type".PadRight(20), "Time", "GC(0)", "GC(1)", "GC(2)");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                TestPerformance(s => s);
                TestPerformance<UnsafeFixedString>(s => s);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void TestPerformance<T>(Func<string, T> func)
        {
            var buffer = new T[BufferSize];
            GC.Collect(2);
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            var initialCollectionCounts = new int[] { GC.CollectionCount(0), GC.CollectionCount(1), GC.CollectionCount(2) };
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < LoopCount; i++)
                buffer[i % BufferSize] = func(String.Format("{0}", i));
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
                typeof(T).Name.PadRight(20),
                stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                (GC.CollectionCount(0) - initialCollectionCounts[0]),
                (GC.CollectionCount(1) - initialCollectionCounts[1]),
                (GC.CollectionCount(2) - initialCollectionCounts[2])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Output on my computer is:

```
Type                    Time    GC(0)   GC(1)   GC(2)

String                  5746    160     71      19
UnsafeFixedString       5345    418     0       0
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid generation 2 garbage collection in the first place?

Comment: The application has some real-time requirements. A GC(2) causes a complete freeze.

Comment: What if you store message as byte[]  (encoding.utf8.getbytes() instead of strings?

Comment: I added UTF8PackedString to the example app. Besides being a lot slower, the result is the same with lots of GC2:s. Same if you BlockCopy to a char array.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should keep in mind that most platforms with a GC are not real-time platforms (at least without compromising the integrity of the GC as a memory manager), .NET itself is not a real-time platform and I think Windows isn't considered a real-time platform either.

Comment: RT-demands are soft. No one will die. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should not be a surprise that a `struct` with a `string` field makes do difference here: a `string` field is *always* simply a reference to an object on the managed heap - specifically, a `string` object somewhere. The `string` will still exist and still cause GC2 eventually.

The only way to "fix" this is to not have it as an object *at all*; and the only way to do that (without going completely outside of managed memory) is to use a `fixed` buffer:

```
public unsafe struct FixedString
{
    private fixed char str[100];
}
```

Here, **every** struct instance `FixedString` has 200 bytes reserved for the data. `str` is simply a relative offset to the `char*` that marks the start of this reservation. However, *working* with this is tricky - and requires `unsafe` code throughout. Also note that every `FixedString` reserves the same amount of space regardless of whether you actually want to store 3 characters or 170. To avoid memory issues, you would either need to use null-teriminators, or store the payload length separately.

Note that in .NET 4.5, the [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) support makes it possible to have a decent sized array of such values (a `FixedString[]`, for example) - but note that you don't want to copy the data very often. To avoid that, you would want to always allow spare space in the array (so you don't copy the entire array just to add one item), and work with individual items via `ref`, i.e.

```
FixedString[] data = ...
int index = ...
ProcessItem(ref data[index]);

void ProcessItem(ref FixedString item) {
    // ...
}
```

Here `item` is talking directly to the element **in the array** - we have not copied the data out at any point.

Now we only have one *object* - the array itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marc! Just got it working. The "unsafe" and "fixed" keywords made the difference. I will make it an answer and update the code. I think I spot my thought error also: The annotations I used in the original example are just for marshaling and do not guide how .net organizes the struct in memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
    const int BufferSize = 1000000;
```

Your buffer is simply too large, thus being capable of storing a string reference for too long and allowing them to be promoted past gen#1.  Experimenting with the buffer size provides this solution:

```
    const int BufferSize = 180000;
```

No more GC(2) collections.

You could infer the gen#1 heap size from this.  Albeit it is difficult to do for this test program, the string sizes are too variable.  Hand-tuning would be required in a real app anyway.

Comment: The app requires the log to be big enough and the entries long-lived enough to make them advance to generation 2. That was what I wanted to simulate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although i liked Marc Gravell and Hans Passant answers (as always)...

You can fine tune the GC in order to run concurrently and hence avoid the freeze times. 
Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection)

Comment: I think that workstation+concurrent is the default mode on a workstation OS and it causes some of my threads to freeze for a few 100 ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a buffer of `StringBuilder`s would essentially be the exact same thing as the `unsafe fixed char[]` approach.  But give you the potential flexibility of the length of a particular string going beyond what you initially allocated (of course, yes, that would cause that one string, or more precisely the underlying `char[]` of the `StringBuilder` to be eligible for garbage collection, but let's be practical).  Also, you don't have to do your own string length management.

```
private static void TestPerformance2()
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder[BufferSize];
    // Initialize each item of the array.  This is no different than what
    // unsafe struct is.
    for (int i = 0; i < BufferSize; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = new StringBuilder(256);
    }

    GC.Collect(2);
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var initialCollectionCounts = new int[] { GC.CollectionCount(0), GC.CollectionCount(1), GC.CollectionCount(2) };
    stopWatch.Reset();
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < LoopCount; i++)
    {
        buffer[i % BufferSize].Clear(); // Or use .Length = 0;, which is what the Clear() method does internally.

        buffer[i % BufferSize].AppendFormat("{0}", i);
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
        typeof(StringBuilder).Name.PadRight(20),
        stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        (GC.CollectionCount(0) - initialCollectionCounts[0]),
        (GC.CollectionCount(1) - initialCollectionCounts[1]),
        (GC.CollectionCount(2) - initialCollectionCounts[2])
    );
}
```

And the results, twice as fast (you can even move the stopwatch up to include the array initialization and it's still faster than the `UnsafeFixedString`).

```
Type                    Time    GC(0)   GC(1)   GC(2)

String                  4647    131     108     23
StringBuilder           2600    94      0       0
UnsafeFixedString       5135    161     0       0
```