# Equal strings aren't equal (==) in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Strings in Java : equals vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281448/strings-in-java-equals-vs)

Why is this Java code not working correctly? The if statement is always being read as False, invariably giving an output of 4 for any input, including Anish & "Anish".

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class lkjlj {  
    public static void main(String args []) {  
        Scanner Pillai = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter Your name");  
        String nabeel = Pillai.nextLine();  
        System.out.println(nabeel);  
        if (nabeel == "Anish") {  
            System.out.println("Your Age is 6");  
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your age is 4");  
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: As a matter of style, you should use pillai (lowercase) instead of Pillai (captalized). Captalized words are normally used for class names.

Answer (score 12):

You should use .equals for String comparisons, not ==.

Comment: +1 good answer though explanation why especially for the OP being Java beginner would be appreciated. Luckly others provided it.

Comment: Well, considering how many times the question has been asked, it didn't seem worth it to answer it in detail.  I knew it would be closed as a duplicate quickly.

Answer (score 10):

Use this: `nabeel.equals("Anish")`

In Java, `String.equals` checks if two strings have the **same content**, while `==` checks if they are the **same object**.

Answer (score 8):

use

```
if(nabeel.equals("Anish"))
{
...
}
```

because,
To compare Strings for equality, don't use ==. The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Two strings may be different objects, but have the same value (have exactly the same characters in them). Use the .equals() method to compare strings for equality.

Comment: +1 @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy @Jen good explanation.