# How can this equality statement be false?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equal strings aren't equal (==) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178585/equal-strings-arent-equal-in-java)

From Eclipse's Display window:

```
 messages.get(i).getMsg() == lastMsg
 (boolean) false
 messages.get(i).getMsg().length()
 (int) 14
 lastMsg.length()
 (int) 14
 messages.get(i).getMsg()
 (java.lang.String) INSERT QUARTER
 lastMsg
 (java.lang.String) INSERT QUARTER
```

Fairly new to Java.  How can the first statement be false?  Am I missing something ridiculously simple here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare strings in Java, you should do that by calling the `equals()` method, not by using the `==` operator.

The `==` operator does not test if the value or content of two objects is the same. It simply checks if the two expressions on both sides of the `==` refer to the exact same object. If you have two `String` objects that have the same content, but that are distinct objects, then `==` will return `false`.

(There is a minor complication to this though: the compiler does some clever tricks so that if you use string literals, `==` will actually return `true`).

```
String msg = messages.get(i).getMsg();
System.out.println(msg == lastMsg); // false
System.out.println(msg.equals(lastMsg)); // true
```

Comment: If you use string literals, they will end up as the same object not only thanks to clever compiler tricks, but as a result of the language spec.

Comment: Yes @Thilo, I didn't want to go into that too much here as it would probably just confuse AngryHacker.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings with `==` - which means you're actually seeing whether the two string *references* are references to the same string object.

It looks like you've actually got two distinct string objects which are *equal* - so you need to use `equals`:

```
messages.get(i).getMsg().equals(lastMsg) // Should print true
```

This is a very common mistake for those new to Java, so don't feel bad :) Operators can't be overloaded in Java, so for reference types, `==` *always* compares the references themselves, a sort of *identity comparison* rather than an equivalence comparison.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares the references and not the string content. If you want to compare strings in java use [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
lastMsg.equals(messages.get(i).getMsg())
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with String in Java and checking for equality you should be using equals and not ==

Answer (score 1):

"==" operator compares objects' references. use method `equals()` to compare objects themselves

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like `messages.get(i).getMsg()` returns a **String** and `lastMsg` is also a **String**. If you use the `==` to test equality, you're actually comparing the instances and it's returning false because the 2 Strings are 2 different instances eventhough the String that they represent are the same. You need to use Object's .equals() method to compare the quality of Objects. See also: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from the C/C++ world, then this is a classic Java "gotcha".

The comparison operator (==) is generally "true" when the objects on both sides of the == **are the same object**, and not because the members of both objects are equivalent.