# A strange String assignment phnomenon in Java

Tags: string, boolean, variable-assignment, equals

```
public static void main(String[] args){

/* lots of codes */

    if(profile.addFriend(buffernametwo)){
      boolean a = profile.addFriend(buffernametwo);
      System.out.println(a); 
     //prints false; however if I directly put profile.addFriend(buffernametwo) 
     //and follow the debugger, it will appear true

      /* lots of codes */

    }
/* lots of codes */

//the following method is in a different class

public boolean addFriend(String friend) {

        for(int i = 0;i < profile_friend.size();i++){
        //Here is the point
            if(friend == profile_friend.get(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        profile_friend.add(friend);
        return true;

/* lots of codes */

private ArrayList<String> profile_friend = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

The question is in the comment of the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings in Java : equals vs ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281448/strings-in-java-equals-vs)

Comment: your question would be clearer if `tester()` didn't return false for a match and true for a mismatch.

Comment: Man, you completely changed the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to. This is my real question. My simplified version diverts my intention.

Answer (score 3):

There is a String pool in Java so here they coincidentaly have the same reference. But you shouldn't rely on this and always use `equals()` when comparing Strings.

Comment: Well, it seems my simplified version doesn't show the awkwardness completely. I'll edit it in the question

Comment: it's not coincidental, it's required by the Java Language Specification - all string constants are interned.

Comment: OK, i put my original code in the box. Please help me out. thx

Answer (score 0):

Because the == compares the references and both `abc` and `bcd` are pointing to two same memory location. `equals()` function suggested by @jan Zyka is the correct option to compare two different strings.

However if you intentionally want that both the `abc` and `bcd` should point the same memory location, You can use `intern()` method of String class... read documentation [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/06/all_about_inter.html).

Comment: His two intances in the example already have same memory location. That is what surprised him.

Comment: yea, but unfortunately that is not true across JVM implementations. If someone intentionally want to share the memory address along Sting references than the ideal way will be to use intern()...

Comment: @amit there's no need to intern string constants, it's automatic and required by the JLS.

Comment: OK, i put my original code in the box. Please help me out. thx