# toUpperCase not functioning as I'd expect

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [Strings in Java : equals vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281448/strings-in-java-equals-vs)

I have two Strings; one is "hello" in lower case and one is "HELLO" in upper.

When I apply toUpperCase to the variables and then use a boolean to compare them, they are coming out as not equal and I can't figure out why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "hello";
    String b = "HELLO";

    a = a.toUpperCase();
    b = b.toUpperCase();

    boolean c = (a==b);

    System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
}
```

The output is HELLO HELLO false but it should be HELLO HELLO true. Shouldn't it?
What am I missing?

Comment: what if it wasn't a problem with uppercase?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `==` and `String.equals()`.

Comment: Your mistaken - the == usually does work as expected for identical Strings

Comment: @Imray `==` works "as expected" only if you pass the same string objects around or work with interned strings. You can convince yourself that `new String("hi") == new String("hi")` is false by running a simple test.

Comment: @Imray BTW, `"hi" == "hi"` is true because the compiler is clever enough to save space and actually use the same object for both `"hi"`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toUpperCase` is working correctly. You have to use `equals` to check for equality of both Strings.

```
boolean c = a.equals(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

`String.toUpperCase()` creates a new object so

```
boolean c = (a==b);
```

will be false as you're comparing 2 different `String` references here.

You can use

```
boolean c = a.equals(b);
```

to check String content.

Comment: But if you create two String objects with exactly the same content, the == does work properly on them. Therefore, I don't believe the == is comparing references.

Comment: It will _only_ work (return true) if there is no conversion is done in so the same object is returned and the other object reference is the same. Here a new object is returned from `a.toUpperCase()` but not from `b.toUpperCase()`. The `==` operator always compares references.

Answer (score 1):

**Here '=' checks the reference and .equals compare the actual content**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "hello";
    String b = "HELLO";

    a = a.toUpperCase();
    b = b.toUpperCase();

    boolean c = (a.equals(b));

    System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
}
```

**If you want to use '=' then try this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "hello";
    String b = "HELLO";

    a = a.toUpperCase();
    b = a;

    boolean c = (a==b);

    System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the string compare that's not right, not the `toUpperCase()`

Do this instead:

```
boolean c = a.equals(b);
```

This is because the objects are equal by their values, but you still have two different object instances.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two string object references(which obviously aren't the same). Instead you could just use a.equal(b)

So your edit should be :

String a = "hello";
    String b = "HELLO";

```
a = a.toUpperCase();
b = b.toUpperCase();

boolean c = (a.equals(b));

System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
```

}