# Do string literals get optimised by the compiler?

Tags: c#, string, optimization

Does the C# compiler or .NET CLR do any clever memory optimisation of string literals/constants?  I could swear I'd heard of the concept of "string internalisation" so that in any two bits of code in a program, the literal "this is a string" would actually refer to the same object (presumably safe, what with strings being immutable?).  I can't find any useful reference to it on Google though...

Have I heard this wrong?  Don't worry - I'm not doing anything horrible in my code with this information, just want to better my understanding of how it works under the covers.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/372547/38206

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EDIT: While I strongly suspect the statement below is true for all C# compiler implementations, I'm not sure it's actually guaranteed in the spec. Section 2.4.4.5 of the spec talks about *literals* referring to the same string instance, but it doesn't mention other constant string expressions. I *suspect* this is an oversight in the spec - I'll email Mads and Eric about it.

---

It's not just string literals. It's any string *constant*. So for example, consider:

```
public const string X = "X";
public const string Y = "Y";
public const string XY = "XY";

void Foo()
{
    string z = X + Y;
}
```

The compiler realises that the concatenation here (for `z`) is between two constant strings, and so the result is also a constant string. Therefore the initial value of `z` will be the same reference as the value of `XY`, because they're compile-time constants with the same value.

EDIT: The reply from Mads and Eric suggested that in the Microsoft C# compiler string constants and string literals *are* usually treated the same way - but that other implementations may differ.

Comment: Do two identical string constants in different assemblies point to the same object too? / Does the jitter intern string literals?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I believe that depends on the `CompilationRelaxationsAttribute(CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning)` attribute. I wouldn't like to say for sure though.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, please advice whether interned strings with same content always have the same reference? Does it mean that comparing references of such strings will return true?

Comment: @Johnny_D: Yes and yes - guaranteed within the same assembly, at least. Between assemblies it gets trickier, IIRC.

Answer (score 10):

[This article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) explains string interning pretty well. Quote:

> .NET has the concept of an "intern
>   pool". It's basically just a set of
>   strings, but it makes sure that every
>   time you reference the same string
>   literal, you get a reference to the
>   same string. This is probably
>   language-dependent, but it's certainly
>   true in C# and VB.NET, and I'd be very
>   surprised to see a language it didn't
>   hold for, as IL makes it very easy to
>   do (probably easier than failing to
>   intern literals). As well as literals
>   being automatically interned, you can
>   intern strings manually with the
>   Intern method, and check whether or
>   not there is already an interned
>   string with the same character
>   sequence in the pool using the
>   IsInterned method. This somewhat
>   unintuitively returns a string rather
>   than a boolean - if an equal string is
>   in the pool, a reference to that
>   string is returned. Otherwise, null is
>   returned. Likewise, the Intern method
>   returns a reference to an interned
>   string - either the string you passed
>   in if was already in the pool, or a
>   newly created interned string, or an
>   equal string which was already in the
>   pool.

Comment: Sidenote: Since internend strings aren't freed during the live-time of the AppDomain improper use of intering can cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it does optimize string literals. One simple example where you can see that:

```
string s1="A";
string s2="A";
object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2);  //true
```