# Assigning a string-literal to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, assignment-operator, string-literals

Do string-literals have a particular type in C# (like const char* in c++) or does C# just create a new string object for each string-literal that appears in a program ? 
I am curious to understand what happens behind the scene when the following statement is executed:

```
string s1 = "OldValue";
```

does this call a particular method in the string class (a constructor, or an impicit conversion operator, ...) or does C# create a new string object that contains "OldValue" ( then just assign its reference to s1, just like it would for any reference type ) ?

i am trying to understand what it is in the design of the string class that garantees the value of s1 remains "OldValue":

```
string s2 = s1;
s2 = "NewValue";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286614/c-sharp-do-string-literals-get-optimised-by-the-compiler

Comment: Do you know what is [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2.aspx)?

Comment: @Sinatr : yes I know what ref-types are. just trying to understand : when i write s2 = "NewValue" , does it mean that a string object with value "NewValue" was created, and then a refernce to it is assigned to s2 ?  it seems to be the case, judging from what quetzalcoatl's answer below

Answer (score 6):

To you last question, why values were preserved - it is not in the String class. It is in the way that object references work.

The String class is not a **value type**, it is a **reference type**. It is a full-featured object that is not copied-around when "passed intto/from variables".

When you write:

```
string s1 = "mom";
string s2 = s1;
string s3 = s1;
s3 = "dad";
```

there is only one instance of "mom", that is first created somewhere in the heap, then **a reference to it** is assigned to s1. Then another reference is created and assigned to s2. Then another reference is created and assigned to s3. No copies. References. Like for any **real, normal CLR object**.

Finally, in the last line, another string is created on the heap and then a reference to it is assigned to the s3 variable. Note that this sentence says *absoltely nothing* about the "mom" or s1/s2 variables. They didn't note a thing.

Remember that String is not a value-type. It is just an normal immutable object that has some handy Equals and GetHashCode overrides. String class has some little magic inside, but it is not relevant here.

Comment: Nice answer, in looking up details for this question I discovered something I didn't know. The CLR implements a flyweight pattern as far as different string literals of an exact same value are concerned. Duplicate string literals are actually assigned to the same reference object.

Comment: @AntonioHaley That's called string interning. You can invoke it yourself using [`string.Intern()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl : thanks ! so regarding my first question : string s1 ="mom" means that a string object with value "mom" is first created, then s1 is set to "point" to it...so string literals are treated just like normal string objects (meaning everything time a string literal is mentioned in the code, a string object is created to contain it).

Comment: @sam95: you start to get it. but no, it is not like that. Strings literals are (or may be) **interned automatically**. This means that in `var s1 = "mom"; var s2 = "mom"; var s3 = "mom"` and even in completely different class `var tadam = "mom"` the compiler will notice that the same exact stringliteral exists 4 times and will create **only one** string-literal-entry in the compiled assembly. Later when executing, the runtime notices that a string-from-literal-table is used and will **not create duplicates** but will reuse the same string object whenever that literal-entry was referenced.

Comment: @sam95: the reason is simple: `string` objects are assumed and designed to be immutable. Hence, there is no real reason **not to intern** strings that are hardcoded in the code. Since they are written directly in code, they **will** be used at some point of time and they will be always the same and since they are 'code' you want them to be *fast*. Other strings created at runtime from user/file/network/etc data, can be **larger** and **their contents wary much** hence there's no automatic interning of them. It would spam the intern pool too much, so careful with `string.Intern()` method.

Comment: And one more thing: string interning **has nothing to do** with original question of `var s1="mom"; var s2 = s1; s2 = "dad"`. Here literals "mom" and "dad" exist only once, so you'd not even notice any interning. The "preservation" and "single-instance" of "mom" object here is completely due to the way the code is written: one fetch-literal("mom"), reference-assign, reference-assign, one fetch-literal("dad"), reference-assign.

Comment: In the answer I written "in the last line, another string is created on the heap" very loosely to make you focus on **references vs. objects**. The fact that the string was not actually "created" at that point and only a ref-to-intern-pool was used was irrelevant. Moreover, IIRC, the interning might be skipped at all for some very small strings, but I wouldn't be digging there now. In (100%-epsilon) of cases it's completly transparent to you..

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Actually in c# strings are stored in the format of buffer array where in every string declaration required 20bytes to store data and post that 2 bytes for each character.
so whenever you declare any string for e.g. string s1 = 'Bhushan';
then on string buffer will be created and will have memory requirements as follows,

Bytes required for Data (Overhead) : 20 Bytes
2 bytes per character so (2 * 7) : 14 Bytes
Overall it will required 20 + 14 = 34 Bytes.

Answer (score 0):

string is an immutable class, that means every time we change the value, it will create new instance.

```
string s2 = s1;
s2 = "NewValue";
```

it can be explain like this.

```
string s2 = s1;
s2 = new string("NewValue"); // It doesn't compile, just an example.
```

And for string modification, it can be explained like this.

```
string s = "blah";
s.Insert(0, "blah"); // s is a new instance
```

The same like:

```
string s = "blah";
s = new string("blah") + new string("blah"); // Doesn't compile, just an explanation
```