# If string is used as an argument, does string still float around the memory?

Tags: c#, string, security, memory, passwords

If string is being used as an argument, is it still in memory??

for example,

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("userid=ididid; userpassword=pwpwpw");
```

is there a potential threat to a security breach?

I wonder how GC is working on a string that is being used as argument only...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190938/is-securestring-ever-practical-in-a-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little you can do with strings supplied as string constants: they are [*interned*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4286658/335858), so they would not be garbage collected until your program exits.

Note that using [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) would not help in this situation, because if you copy the content of a string literal into an instance of `SecureString`, your string literal would remain in the image of your program.

On the other hand, when the source of your string is *not* a literal or a constant, you would be able to prevent the content of your string from remaining in memory longer than you need it:

```
OracleConnection conn;
using (var pwd = new SecureString()) {
    pwd.Append(...); // Append characters of the password to the string
    ... // Append more characters...
    conn = new OracleConnection(pwd);
}
// At this point pwd is erased from memory
```