# Why Does Assert.AreSame() Consider Two Seperate Strings The Same?

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, mstest

Why is this passing `Assert.AreSame()`?

```
[TestMethod]
public void StringSameTest()
{
      string a = "Hello";
      string b = "Hello";

      Assert.AreSame(a, b);
}
```

I understand ìt tests for reference equality, and is essentially the same as `Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))` but it's clear that `a` and `b` are different string objects, regardless of them having the same values. If Ì set `string b = a;` I'd expect true, but that's not the case. Why isn't this test failing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler [will **intern** identical literal strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) to the same const string reference.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
private const String _hello = "Hello";

[TestMethod]
public void StringSameTest()
{
      string a = _hello;
      string b = _hello;

      Assert.AreSame( a, b ); // true
}
```

To create a separate string instance that's identical to a const string use `String.Copy()`:

```
string a = "Hello";
string b = a.Copy();

Assert.AreSame( a, b ); // false
```

However, do note that:

- `String.Copy()` and `String.Clone()` are different!

  - `Clone()` does not actually clone the string value, it instead returns a reference to itself.
  - `String.ToString()` also returns a reference to itself.
- `String.Copy()` is deprecated in .NET Framework and .NET Core and may be removed in a future version.

  - This is because [there is no legitimate need to use `String.Copy()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27515)

See [Do string literals get optimised by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286614/do-string-literals-get-optimised-by-the-compiler)

Comment: Huh, looks like the C# compiler is a lot smarter than I am. Can you speak more about the *intern*? I've never heard of that word in this context. Every time I search "Compiler intern" on Google I get a list of job adverts for a compiler developer.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk Search for "string intern c#"