# Object instance layout: string literals?

Tags: clr, internals

Please, can anyone provide more detail on the figure from the ["How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7) article?

[image]

I'm confused with "string literals" section, I'm not able to find any reason to store those as the part of every object instance and I even could not deduct what is really stored there:

[#US (user string) stream record id](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-13905.html)? No, those emitted directly into IL as a ldstr param and are hardcoded into the JITted code at runtime. There's no need to store it as a part of each instance.

Runtime-interned instances? Again, no. First, they are usual object instances and the intern table is [just a GC root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372547/where-do-java-and-net-string-literals-reside/372559#372559) used to keep the interned strings from being GC'ed.
Second, there may be arbitrary number of runtime-interned strings, so we'll have no way to infer the [Base Instance Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S9)

Just a meaningless picture and the string literals (whatever the authors implied) are not stored as a part of the object instance? Don't know.