# Static objects are pinned and cannot be reallocated by GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, sos, windb

I have a static variable in my class, when I look at this object via windbg/sos, it shows this object as Pinned. I assume that this mean GC cannot allocate this object anywhere else. Any ideas why static variables are treated as pinned?

Here is the declaration of this variable in my class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static string Name = "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";  
    }  
}
```

and here is the output form windbg

```
0:004> !do 0231bb70   
Name:        System.String  
MethodTable: 6c97f92c  
EEClass:     6c6b8ba0  
Size:        418(0x1a2) bytes  
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll  
String:        Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    
Fields:    
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name  
6c9828f8  4000103        4         System.Int32  1 instance      202 m_stringLength  
6c981d48  4000104        8          System.Char  1 instance       41 m_firstChar  
6c97f92c  4000105        8        System.String  0   shared   static Empty  
    >> Domain:Value  004f6588:02311228 <<  
0:004> !gcroot 0231bb70   
Scan Thread 0 OSTHread 2824  
Scan Thread 2 OSTHread 1ae0  
DOMAIN(004F6588):HANDLE(Pinned):1613f4:Root:  03312020(System.Object[])->
  0231bb70(System.String)  
DOMAIN(004F6588):HANDLE(Pinned):1613fc:Root:  03311010(System.Object[])->
  0231bb70(System.String)
```

See in the output of !gcroot this is displayed as HANDLE(PINNED). Am I misreading this output?

Comment: why windbg shows is as PINNED then?

Comment: Can you show the WinDbg output?

Comment: Updated question with code and windbg output

Comment: Try it with a reference object other than a string. Strings are immutable and native to the CLR. Since the value is a string literal and can never be changed it may give it special treatment and place it so that it never has to be moved.

Comment: Yeah with ref type it does not show as pinned.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the string is pinned is not because you have a static reference, but because you have a string literal. String literals are interned by default, and thus you'll see them as pinned. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372547/38206) as well.